# Rollupjs: Ignore lines of code

Tags: lodash, rollupjs

One of my javascript files is using the lodash template syntax:

```
const deliveryClient = new DeliveryClient({
enablePreviewMode: <%= options.enablePreviewMode %>,
projectId: '<%= options.projectId %>',
previewApiKey: '<%= options.previewApiKey %>',
defaultLanguage: '<%= options.defaultLanguage %>',
enableAdvancedLogging: <%= options.enableAdvancedLogging %>,
baseUrl: '<%= options.baseUrl %>',
typeResolvers: typeResolvers
});
```

But when i run rollup -c i'm getting a "unexpected token" error. Is there a way to tell rollup to ignore (just put it in the output file) some lines of code?

Or is there an other/better way to deal with lodash template syntax within RollupJS?

I just want to above code snippet to be in my final output!

Comment: Yes - run the linter on the generated source code not the template... -_-

Comment: @user234461 Thanks for your reply but the issue is that i am not able to compile my javascript with rollupjs (it is not about linting). I rephrased the question and removed the linting example because this might have been confusing.

Comment: If rollup is meant to be "compiling" the JS, then surely it cannot possibly recognise `<%=` as a valid token and neither can any runtime tool. I'm not familiar with Lodash, but a brief glance at the API docs suggests it expects templates to be expressed as string literals. Or are you actually *generating* JS source code using Lodash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by using the [rollup-plugin-replace plugin](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-replace).

In my javascript I changed my code into the following:

```js
const deliveryClient = new DeliveryClient('KENTICOOPTIONS');
```

and in the `rollup.config.js` I added the plugin with the following configuration:

```js
replace({
  include: 'lib/templates/plugin.template.js',
  KENTICOOPTIONS: '<%= serialize(options) %>'
})
```

So this gives the final output of:

```
const deliveryClient = new DeliveryClient('<%= serialize(options) %>');
```

Which is exactly what i needed!